# How to get a background color to cover sibling image?

Tags: html, css

I want the white background for the post-text-container to pull up a little to cover the bottom part of the image (hence the `margin-top`). For some reason it's not white currently, it's transparent.

Whats going wrong?

```css
body {
  background-color:#EEF;
}

.post-container img {
  max-width: 385px;
}

.post-text-container {
  background: #ffffff;
  padding: 15px;
  margin-top: -65px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="post-container">
  <img src="//via.placeholder.com/350x100" alt="" id="feat-img" />

  <div class="post-text-container">

    <h2>Heading</h2>
    <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
    <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>

  </div>
  <!-- End post-text-container -->

</div>
<!-- End post-container -->
```

Comment: Tried that too. Same

Comment: [Seems to work for me](https://jsfiddle.net/5zzoe78p/). Maybe there is some other CSS at play? You might check for styles that override the ones shown here.

Comment: The `background: #fffff;` should work fine, so @showdev is probably right.  Did you right-click and inspect-element to see the rule being used?  Also, you could try increasing your selector's specificity, e.g. `div.post-container div.post-text-container`, or add `!important` to test

Comment: maybe, you can create an extra class and mark the background color as important, only for the area that you need.

Comment: Is it possible to add the entire CSS code there? It may impacted other CSS code. It is working for me.

Comment: So basically what I want is to have a white background for the post-text-container and want it to pull it up a little to cover the bottom part of the image (hence the - margin-top). Tried the above mentioned suggestions but still don't have any background.

Answer (score 2):

I see what you mean now.
It looks like the issue is due to a lack of [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context).

I added `position:relative` to create a stacking context.

```css
body {
  background-color: #EEF;
}

.post-text-container {
  position: relative; /* Added this */
  background: #ffffff;
  padding: 15px;
  margin-top: -65px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="post-container">

  <img src="//via.placeholder.com/350x100" alt="" id="feat-img" />

  <div class="post-text-container">
    <h2>Heading</h2>
    <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score -5):

your stylesheet seems to be working fine.

add this style

```
body{
   background-color: #ccc; //something other than white
}
```

are you sure the `background-color` of your `body` element or `post-text-container`'s parent element is not white?

see this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yLu1sxmj/257/)

Comment: This is not an answer - also the code snippet above does what JSFiddle does

Comment: it is possible his body bgcolor might be the same as his div bgcolor as seen
 by running his code snippet.